# Why This Loop Always Produce N+1 Output?

Tags: php

Let's say I have this inputs :

```
<input type="hidden" name="block-1" value="001"/>
<input type="hidden" name="block-2" value="012"/>
<input type="hidden" name="block-3" value="002"/>
<input type="hidden" name="block-4" value="005"/>
<input type="hidden" name="block-5" value="008"/>
```

and I want to process those input using this PHP loop

```
$i = 1;

do {
    $x = 'block-'.$i;
    $webBlock = $_POST[$x];
    //some codes here
    $i++;
}

while (!empty($webBlock));
```

why I always have 6 outputs? and the last one is blank output. seems that loop always doing n+1. how to make correct loop based on number of inputs given? thanks!

Comment: khan : sure. I'm trying all possibilities now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need `while`?

I'd go with:

```
$i=0;
foreach($_POST as $name => $value)
{
   if( strpos($name , 'block-') !== false ) echo $i . " - " . $name . ": " . $value;
   $i++;
}
```

Believe that should account for items named '`block-n`'. The `if` statement basically says "if `block-` is anywhere in the name of the field, echo out such and such".
Let me know if you get an error and will amend.

Comment: because I need $i. can 'foreach' provide that?

Comment: bro, I just notice that I have 3 more <input type="hidden"> under the code. this will cause N+3 now... how to have foreach loop but specific to $_POST[$x] and $x = 'block-'.$i;

Comment: @RobertHanson Give us a moment and I'll write it up

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$i = 0;

do {
    $i++;
    $x = 'block-'.$i;
    $webBlock = $_POST[$x];
    //some codes here
}
while (!empty($webBlock));
```

**UPD**: The best approach is this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($_POST); $i++) {
    $webBlock = $_POST['block-'.$i];
    //some code here
}
```

Comment: You are right, my bad. Updated with the most correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a repeat loop, you should use a while loop:

```
while (!empty($webBlock)){
    $x = 'block-'.$i;
    $webBlock = $_POST[$x];
    //some codes here
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

beacause do will get executed at least once what ever may be in while expression .`do while is an exit control loop.`

Answer (score 0):

Because You are using `Do While loop`.I am not sure about your data but i must say that it will execute one more time as you expected.Let us check it by iterating
It will run first time because `$webBlock` is not empty and same as for 5 times.
Now here you want to close the loop but your 5th iteration's condition gets true.Now it will execute once more and show nothing (because there is nothing in $webBlock)and now condition will find that `$webBlock` is empty.
I suggest you to use `while loop` here.It will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

I am not a PHP developer so I will just give you general idea about what you are doing.

Actually you are using `Do-while` loop which is sometimes called Exit Control loop. So, in case of Do-While after executing code your condition will be checked. So, even you didn't get any value in 'webBlock' your code will be executed. So, this is your bug.

Instead of this you can use  `While` loop, Entry control loop. You code is executed if and only if condition is true.

```
$i = 1;
while (i>0) {
     $x = 'block-'.$i;
     $webBlock = $_POST[$x];
    if(empty($webBlock))
    {
      break;
   }
   $i++;
}
```